# SOAP POST Request using VBScript

Tags: javascript, http, post, soap, vbscript

I am looking for a simple way to send a *POST* request on a web service and receive a response as well using *VBScript*. So far, I have found a way to send a *GET* request using the code below:

```
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
http.open "GET", "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL", FALSE
http.send ""
WScript.Echo http.responseText
```

Please note that I chose *VBScript* because I am planning to create scheduled task using `Task Scheduler` on server. If there are any other ways to do this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change "GET" to "POST" ?

Comment: @AlexK. Will that allow me to send my own SOAP request? Sorry, I am not that knowledgable in VBScript and SOAP.

Comment: Yes, if you pass the correct xml to `send`

Comment: Hi @AlexK, do you have any idea on error 80004005 (details mentioned on the comment below)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"POST"` instead of `"GET"`. That will create a HTTP Post request.

If you want to send anything as post data, you can do it with `http.send`

#### Sending form data

```
http.send "Name=John+Doe&Age=40&foo=bar&foobar=foobaz"
```

#### Sending a SOAP request

```
http.send "<?xml version="1.0"?><soap:Envelope ...... </soap:Envelope>"
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting error message of "Unspecified error" with code 80004005. Can you please help me with this? I've got my soap request from my SOAP UI, and it works there. So I am pretty sure my request is correct.

Comment: I just googled the error code and found out that it might be caused by permission restrictions. Not sure why but I am running the soap request on the server with admin access, same account I used when using SOAP UI.

Comment: Maybe your firewall is blocking your application.

Comment: Hi, @Krumia. I removed `<?xml version="1.0"?>` from my code, and now, when I run the code in command line, I have to wait for a second, and then nothing happens. It just came to my mind that the request was probably sent to the service and I only not getting the response due to strange reason (Possibly because my request is in invalid format)?

Comment: Also, is a **.svc** file extension valid to be the second argument of the `post` method here?

Comment: Hi, @Krumia. The possiblity that I am blocked by a firewall settings might be crossed out here. Can you please help me understand why I am able to get response when using `GET` but not when using `POST`? I'm pretty sure my xml request is correct cos I am getting them from my SOAP UI which works perfectly fine. Please respond.